# Get data from Abstract to Encapsulation

Tags: python, abstract

I am unable to get the data from the class I've setup as abstract. In this class, if I press '1', it should let me go to the part where I can

- Enter First name and last name:
- Enter Address:
- Enter phone:
- Enter Email-Address:

I honestly don't know where to start.

```
    class Student: # abstract
       def student_submenu (a,select_num):
         a.select_num = select_num

       def ss_1 (z):

         print("\n")
         print(" ===== | SUBMENU - STUDENTS | ===== ")
         print("||                                 ||")
         print("=====================================")
         print(" 1 - ADD NEW STUDENT")
         choice2 = input()
            while choice2 not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
            print("Invalid Please try again")
            return select_num.student_submenu()



      def ss_2 (z1):
        if(choice2 == '1'):
        firstlast = input("Enter First name and last name: ")
        address = input("Enter Address: ")
        phone = input("Enter phone: ")
        email = input("Enter Email-Address: ") 
        print("\n")

        print(firstlast)
        print(address)
        print(phone)
        print(email)

  class Main:  #encapsulation
      def main_page(self):
        print("===== | MAIN MENU |=====")
        print("||                    ||")
        print("========================")
        print("1 - STUDENT ")
        print("2 - SUBJECT ")
        print("3 - QUIT ")
        allchoice = ['1', '2', '3'];
        choice = input()



       while choice not in allchoice:
         print("Invalid Please try again")
         choice = input()

       if choice == '1':
         a = Student()
         a.student_submenu

      elif choice == '2':
         print("back world")
      else:
        quit()

  mainout = Main()
  mainout.main_page()
```

When I run I am getting errors like:

```
line 2
class
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Your indentation is all messed up, not sure if it's from your copy-paste into SO or of it's from your code. It's possible that's why you're getting the error. I recommend using triple ` for your code blocks, especially when working with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is due to indentation. In Python, indentation is very important and must be consistent. Anything at the module level must have no indentation, and when you do indent, you should be consistent (4 spaces is generally the default)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answer to the question: you're using extremely inconsistent and incorrect indentation. If you use improper indentation, you're gonna end up with a lot of errors, including the one you got.

Every new block should be indented by 4 spaces (tabs also work), and everything defined in the global scope (in this case your 2 classes and the last 2 lines of code) should not be indented at all.

Try changing your code to this:

```
class Student: # abstract
    def student_submenu (a,select_num):
        a.select_num = select_num

    def ss_1 (z):
        print("\n")
        print(" ===== | SUBMENU - STUDENTS | ===== ")
        print("||                                 ||")
        print("=====================================")
        print(" 1 - ADD NEW STUDENT")
        choice2 = input()
        while choice2 not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
           print("Invalid Please try again")
        return select_num.student_submenu()



    def ss_2 (z1):
        if(choice2 == '1'):
            firstlast = input("Enter First name and last name: ")
            address = input("Enter Address: ")
            phone = input("Enter phone: ")
            email = input("Enter Email-Address: ") 

            print("\n")
            print(firstlast)
            print(address)
            print(phone)
            print(email)

class Main:  #encapsulation
    def main_page(self):
        print("===== | MAIN MENU |=====")
        print("||                    ||")
        print("========================")
        print("1 - STUDENT ")
        print("2 - SUBJECT ")
        print("3 - QUIT ")
        allchoice = ['1', '2', '3'];
        choice = input()



        while choice not in allchoice:
            print("Invalid Please try again")
            choice = input()
            if choice == '1':
                a = Student()
                a.student_submenu
            elif choice == '2':
                print("back world")
            else:
                quit()

mainout = Main()
mainout.main_page()
```

See also:

- https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation